# Loop through textbox boolean array seperated by commas and mark checkboxes true based on textbox value

Tags: javascript

I cannot figure out how to take a text box '0,1,1,0,1,0,0'
and use the Boolean value separated by comma to mark check boxes true.

I can do this manually by building a if statement. If array.split[0] = 1, set check box 1 true. I do not have access to change the html, only javascript in the code.

I cannot figure out how to loop this process to not type that code for the 15+ check boxes I need to fill.

My expected results are:
Text box has an array of boolean values '0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0'

An equal amount of check boxes exist, in the case above, we can say 11 check boxes.

Each corresponding checkbox will be checked if the value is 1.

So check boxes 2,3,8, and 10 should be checked.

Comment: Actual code would be nice see how to make a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple. Just map the array and check which value is true (1 is true, 0 is false) and then return the position of that  and just add one to it as array index starts from 0

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = () => {
  let boxes = document.querySelector("textarea").value.split(",").map(a => Number(a))
  let allboxes = document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]') 
  allboxes.forEach((a, pos) => {
    if (boxes[pos]) {
      a.checked = true;
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<input class="box" type="checkbox" />
<input class="box" type="checkbox" />
<input class="box" type="checkbox" />
<input class="box" type="checkbox" />
<input class="box" type="checkbox" />
<input class="box" type="checkbox" />
<input class="box" type="checkbox" />
<input class="box" type="checkbox" />
<input class="box" type="checkbox" />
<input class="box" type="checkbox" />
<input class="box" type="checkbox" /><br>
<textarea></textarea><br>
<button>go</button>
```

Comment: The text box mentioned above will be filled already on page-load it will not be filled in by a user, so I just need the code to take what is in the text box, and compare each element to the corresponding check box then mark it true if the element = 1

Comment: textbox can only have 2 values. How do you identify the checkboxes? My code returns the index of checkboxes which have been selected @throwawayaccount12

Comment: The textbox will hold the info of what checkbox needs to be checked.
For example if the text box has '1,0,1,1' (this will be automatically put into the text box on page-load, then 

check box 1 will be checked; checkbox 2 will not, checkboxes 3 and 4 will also be checked.

Comment: Your edit is exactly what's I'm looking for, now I just need to find out how to break down the text box with '0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0' into basically what you names "let boxes="

Answer (score 0):

Probably the following example may be helpful

```js
const input = '0,1,0,1,0'
const values = input.split(',').map(val => parseInt(val));

const checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(checkboxes, (checkbox, index) => {
  checkbox.checked = Boolean(values[index])
})
```

```html
<input class="box" type="checkbox" />
<input class="box" type="checkbox" />
<input class="box" type="checkbox" />
<input class="box" type="checkbox" />
<input class="box" type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: This is perfect but the const values will come from a string in a textbox. So the text box will ahve the string '0,1,0,1,0'. How do I break that up and use each integer to check the boxes?

Comment: @throwawayaccount12 Hi, I have updated the answer according to the requirements